# Sonata Page передать параметры в блок через контейнер

Tags: symfony, sonata

Хочу передать параметры из контейнера в блок, но он не принимает кастомные параметры.
Сервис страницы:

```
class LoginPageService extends DefaultPageService
{

    public function execute(PageInterface $page, Request $request, array $parameters = [], Response $response = null)
    {
        $parameters['test'] = 'test';
        return parent::execute($page, $request, $parameters, $response);
    }
}
```

Вызов контейнера в лэйауте:

```
{{ sonata_page_render_container('content', 'global', {'test': test}) }}
```

Ошибка:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   option "test" does not exist. Defined options are: "attr", "class",
>   "code", "extra_cache_keys", "layout", "manager", "page_id",
>   "template", "ttl", "use_cache".").

Основная идея заключалась в том, чтобы page-сервисом валидировать форму и затем передавать отвалидированные данные формы в блок. Но т.к. я не могу на прямую через контейнер в твиге передать форму, то как мне это сделать? Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

С Сонатой не работал очень давно, однако данную ошибку вызывает OptionsResolver, который используется в формах. В вашем случае не  описан в соответствующей форме параметр test . [Вот как это описано в документации](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html) -

в частности обратите внимание на метод setDefaults.

Как именно вам решить проблему ? Предполагаю что вы где то описываете форму для сонаты или может генерируете (уж простите, я не помню как там все устроено) и в каком то месте наверняка вставляете ее (форму) в блок. Возможно через конфиг.

Вам же нужно либо добавить в setDefaults нужные вам параметры, которые вы предполагаете передавать в форму, в случае если вы описываете форму сами, либо наследовать данную форму и переопределить метод configureOptions где опять же добавляете нужный вам параметр в setDefaults и вызываете метод родителя конечно же.